# Graficando funciones con Django Matplotlib

Tags: python, django, numpy, matplotlib

estoy haciendo un codigo en python que me permite graficar funciones con Django, he usado las librerias de matplotlib y numpy para poder graficarlas. El caso es que, si yo quiero graficarlas en codigo quemado me funciona de maravilla, si le doy la función ya definida por el sistema si me genera la grafica, pero si lo hago para que el usuario escriba por teclado la función para que se grafique me sale un error, alguna idea de que pueda hacer?

Funcion

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
def Graficador(request):
x = symbols('x')
t = np.arange(-10.0, 10.0, 0.010, )
s = (request.POST['funcion'])
s = parse_expr(s)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s)

ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='voltage (mV)',
       title='About as simple as it gets, folks')
ax.grid()
g = mpld3.fig_to_html(fig)
fig.savefig("test.png")

context = {'g': g}

return render(request, 'Graficar.html', context)
```

HTML

```
{% autoescape off %}
<div>{{ g }}</div>
{% endautoescape %}
```

El codigo que adjunté funciona solo con los valores ya establecidos por el sistema, es decir "s" viene siendo la función a graficar, pero no he entendido muy bien como hacer que el usuario pueda entrar por teclado la función que quisiera graficar, alguna idea de que pueda hacer? Gracias, de antemano

Comment: Hmmm... Tu pregunta es prácticamente la misma que [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/479129/intentar-poner-una-entrada-en-funci%c3%b3n-de-gr%c3%a1fico-django-con-matplotlib).

Comment: @padaleiana sí pero esa pregunta no tiene respuestas aceptadas o con votos positivos. De hecho, está pobremente formulada.

Comment: Precisamente. Esta pregunta es más detallada.

Comment: Si, es un codigo de un compañero y yo